# Unit Testing Angular If condition make button disabled

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I try create unit test for this condition

```
  insertForm(index) {
if (this.getForms().length === 0) {
  this.getForms().insert(0, this.formTemplate());
} else {
  this.getForms().insert(index + 1, this.formTemplate());
}
if (this.getForms().length > 99) {
  this.addBtnDisabled = true;
}
```

}

I have 3 condition, and I success make it for 2 first condition, but in the last condition I got out of my expectation, addBtnDisabled should be true. But in karma, it shows false. this is my code in jasmine. what's wrong with my last condition?

```
  it('insert form function should insert new form in index 0 IF GETFORMS.LENGTH IS 0', () => { 
(component.formGroup.get('forms') as FormArray).removeAt(0);
const getFormValue = component.getForms().length;
expect(getFormValue).toEqual(0);
component.insertForm(0);
expect(component.getForms().length).toEqual(1);


 });



 it('insert form function should insert new form in index param + 1 IF GETFORMS.length not equal to 0', () => {
    const getFormLength: number = component.getForms().length;
    const isGetFormLengthtoNotEqual0: boolean = (getFormLength > 0);
    expect(isGetFormLengthtoNotEqual0).toBeTruthy();
    expect(component.getForms().length).toEqual(1);

    spyOn(component.getForms(), 'insert').and.callThrough();

    component.insertForm(1);

    expect(component.getForms().length).toEqual(2);

  });



it('insert form function should addBtnDisabled', () => { // 
    const getFormValue: number = component.getForms().length + 99;
    expect(getFormValue).toEqual(100);
    component.insertForm(100);
    expect(component.addBtnDisabled).toBeTruthy()
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your last test isn't actually setting `component.getForms().length` which means that the length is whatever your initial value. You could do something like:

```
spyOn(component, 'getForms').and.returnValue({length: 100});
const count = component.getForms().length;
component.insertForm(100);

expect(count).toEqual(100);
expect(component.addBtnDisabled).toBeTrue();
```

So you're setting up a spy to watch your component method for `getForms` and when it's called you're setting the returned value. From there you call your `insertForm` method which in-turn sets your add button disabled value.

The reason it's probably not doing what you expected is no where in your function do you appear to actually be changing the length of `getForms()` so that is just stuck at it's initial value.

Comment: when .returnValue({length: 100}) it show error